# Delete nodes that does not contain mesh?

Tags: node-editor, outliner

I'm pretty new on Blender and I have a problem.

I imported a quite huge model hierarchy and some node contains no mesh.
Is there a way to automaticaly delete all node that does not have mesh ?

[image: model outline]

Thanks.

Comment: While this may not work for you, you could try selecting all objects, joining them together with CMD+J, then going into edit mode and pressing p and separating them by disconnected.

Comment: Going by the names these "nodes" that contain no mesh are Empties. (which have no data)  They are quite likely holding parenting info. However to remove _Select > Select All by Type > Empty_  will select then X to remove the selection. Ctrl-Z to undo if it goes awry.

Comment: @batFINGER , Selecting "Empty" by type select all Empty node even if they contains a mesh. So Deleting them (X) delete everything.

Comment: Can try https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/200365/88681

Answer (score -1):

OK. I just learn Python and developped this script :

```
import bpy

# This script selects all objects hierarchy that have mesh on them
# After executing this script, just invert the selection (ctrl+I) and delete (X)

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if o.type == "MESH":
        obj = o
        while True:
            obj.select_set(True)
            obj = obj.parent
            if obj == None:
                break;
```