# What are those black thin lines

Tags: edit-mode

I have downloaded a 3D model in glTF format.
When I import it there are HEAPS of thin lines in the form of a cross all around the model.
Could someone firstly educate me as to what they are and secondly is there an easy method to select them all to remove/delete instead of selecting each one individually and then pressing the 'delete' key. Thanks
[image]

Comment: I don't think that answers my question as I (don't think that I) have empty 'nodes'. I can manually select each one (lmb click) and then hit delete but I thought that there might be a way to get rid of all of them much faster. Does it matter if I leave them as when I select some of them when I delete them a part of the model gets 'moved'. As there appears to be a lot of components (nodes) which have animation attached to them maybe I should try removing those nodes first or at least the animation attached to them?

Comment: if these are empties you can select them all with Shift G > Type, but if these empties are used as parent of objects, as soon as you will delete them, the objects will be back to their original position, it may be what happens now. You could select all the objects and press Alt P (Clear Parent) > Clear and Keep Transformation, which will keep the objects at their current location

Comment: Thanks. I tried shift G > Type which gave an error 'No active object' so I then tried (select all) Alt P Clear parent and also Clear and keep transformation which made some changes but didn't remove all those thin black lines so I manually removed them one by one. I am wondering if because some of the 'parts' to the model such as rudders, landing wheels have animation attached to the nodes if that causes a problem. Tomorrow I will start afresh and select all the nodes which have animation attached to them and delete them and see what happens. Thanks again.

Comment: You can clean up all the ones that *aren't* used for parenting with [this script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/200365/88681).

Comment: Thanks for that script. That's something else I have learned about Blender (using scripts). I used to be a programmer and so might try and learn Python. It looks a bit like the Basic language I used to use 20 years ago.  First time using scripts and I followed a Youtube tutorial, opened a panel for the 'text editor' cut and pasted the script and then selected TEXT > Run script and nothing seemed to happen so either I didn't do it correctly or there were none used for parenting.